# What is this statue about in the throne room Royal Palace Madrid?

Tags: spain, identify-this, madrid, artworks

Recently I visited the Royal Palace in Madrid and in the throne room I saw a statue of what appeared to be a man holding up a small child, about to strike him with an open palm. I'm very curious as to what the this statue is about.

I was unable to photograph the statue as taking photos is forbidden in the palace although I managed to find an image of it on Google, the statue is by the door at the back of the photo.

[image: Throne Room - Royal Palace Madrid]

and a closeup

[image: Close Up of the Statue]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a statue of Saturn, part of the Planets series by Jacques Jonghelinck. Here is an [article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/42711017) that reconstructs the history of the statues, with more detailed pictures on page 126. Given how the myth of [Saturn devouring his son](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_(Rubens)) has been an artistic theme in other occasions, the fate of the child is likely to be much worse than a spanking.

Comment: Thanks, you did well to find that. 
I thought at first it might have shown how the King's brother ascends to the throne by killing the next in line.

Comment: @chrisg42 What? Why would a statue in a royal palace depict something like that? What could make you think that?